# angular file upload with nervgh/angular-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, form-data, angular-file-upload

I'm doing a file upload from angular implementing the https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload plugin, my setup it's like this :

```
var vm = this,
    apiUrl = appConfig.getItem('BASE_API_URL'), // base url;

vm.uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: apiUrl + '/invoices/upload',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": undefined
    }
});

// this function is triggered by a button outside
vm.uploadAll = function () { 
  vm.uploader.uploadAll();
};
```

on the html I have

```
    <input id="uploadFileButton"
       type="file"
       nv-file-select
       uploader="FUCtrl.uploader"
       multiple
       style="display: none;"/> 
    // the display none is due to that this input is click triggered
    // by an outside button
```

the thing is that for start on the client side the post request I see this 
[image]

an image is uploaded (in theory), but the Content-Type is undefined, a missing enctype, and on the other hand on the server side I have this

```
var express = require('express'),
    multer  = require('multer'),
    cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.get('*', function(){});

app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads/'}).single('photo'));

app.post('/upload', function(req, res){

  console.log('hit');

  console.log(req.body); // form fields
  console.log(req.files); // form files
  res.status(204).end();

});

app.listen(3000);
```

but when I recieve the post I see on the console 
    console.log(req.body); // {}
    console.log(req.files); // undefined

and I can't get any data from the pdf's upload

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've discoverded the solution, on the HTML

```
nv-file-select
```

should be

```
nv-file-select=""
```

and remove

```
headers: {
  "Content-Type": undefined
}
```

from the uploader configuration, apparently those things didn't set the content-type and his boundary well, so I toke them out and goy it to work

Answer (score 0):

hey man i don't know about that plugin. but i am using this    https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload plugin and i find very helpful. this is the easiest way to upload a file.

```
Upload with form submit and validations:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/

```
Upload multiple files one by one on file select:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/2vq88rfs/136/

```
Upload multiple files in one request on file select (html5 only):
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/huhjo9jm/5/

```
Upload single file on file select:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/0mz6ff9o/135/

```
Drop and upload with $watch:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/s8kc7wg0/400/

```
Image Crop and Upload
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/xxo3sk41/590/

Comment: same thing as with nervgh

Comment: transformRequest function will try to serialize our FormData object, so we override it with the identity function to leave the data intact. Angular’s default Content-Type header for POST and PUT requests is application/json, so we want to change this, too. By setting ‘Content-Type’: undefined, the browser sets the Content-Type to multipart/form-data for us and fills in the correct boundary. Manually setting ‘Content-Type’: multipart/form-data will fail to fill in the boundary parameter of the request.


https://jsfiddle.net/bk129/2ff06ud3/ it's work for me